# Ctypes read data from a double pointer

Tags: python, pointers, return-value, ctypes

I am working on a C++ Dll with C wrapper and I am creating a Python wrapper for future user (I discover ctypes since monday). One of the method of my Dll (because it is a class) return an `unsigned short **`, call `data`, which corresponds to an image. On C++, I get the value of a pixel using `data[row][column]`.

I create in Python a function on the following model :

```
mydll.cMyFunction.argtypes = [c_void_p]
mydll.cMyFunction.restype = POINTER(POINTER(c_ushort))
```

When I call this function, I have `result = <__main__.LP_LP_c_ushort at 0x577fac8>`
 and when I try to see the data at this address (using `result.contents.contents`) I get the correct value of the first pixel. But I don't know how to access values of the rest of my image. Is there a easy way to do something like C++ (`data[i][j]`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just use `result[i][j]`.  Here's a contrived example:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> ppus = POINTER(POINTER(c_ushort))
>>> ppus
<class '__main__.LP_LP_c_ushort'>
>>> # This creates an array of pointers to ushort[5] arrays
>>> x=(POINTER(c_ushort)*5)(*[cast((c_ushort*5)(n,n+1,n+2,n+3,n+4),POINTER(c_ushort)) for n in range(0,25,5)])
>>> a = cast(x,ppus) # gets a ushort**
>>> a
<__main__.LP_LP_c_ushort object at 0x00000000026F39C8>
>>> a[0] # deref to get the first ushort[5] array
<__main__.LP_c_ushort object at 0x00000000026F33C8>
>>> a[0][0] # get an item from a row
0
>>> a[0][1]
1
>>>
>>> a[1][0]
5
```

So if you are returning the ushort** correctly from C, it should "just work".

Comment: I don't know why I don't try this solution... Maybe the `LP_LP_c_ushort` confused me. Thank you.